# Pydev tags import as "unresolved import" but code using this import works fine.

Tags: python, python-2.7, pydev

I'm fairly new to python and especially it's import mechanism. I'm not entirely sure i'm using the terminology correctly so i should apologize for that up front.

firstly, this seems to be a problem i'm having with a 3rd party import so i can't really change the structure of their release.

In the release, all of the packages are in site-packages/[ROOTFOL]/[PACKAGE]
the [ROOTFOL] does not have a `__init__.py` file, only the package folders have this file.
this folder is placed into site-packages and the site-packages is present in my PYTHONPATH

in the examples they provide, they use it like this:

`import ROOTFOL.PACKAGE.WhateverObject as obj`

I'm trying to avoid adding every single package to the PYTHONPATH as there are a bunch of them. Everything seems to work fine, however it really inhibits my ability to work with the auto-complete functionality and that is the frustrating part.

Something else i find strange, is that when the packages are installed, there is a EGG-INFO folder placed along side the package. In this there are several .txt files and one of which is namespace_packages.txt which has only the ROOTFOL. Is there some way i should be setting this to PyDev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you're seeing here is their distribution model. Usually a module will have one root import that everything stems from, but that's not necessarily the case. They're providing a package with (what I assume) is many modules that don't interact with each other; or they can all stand alone.

instead of importing each package individually, you could use the 'from' keyword:

```
from ROOTFOL.PACKAGE import *
```

which will grab everything inside that sub-module. You could e-mail the developer and ask why they deployed it this way...or you could add your own `__init__.py` to the root folder and,

```
from ROOTFOL import *
```

which will walk the tree. Good luck!

Comment: Well, that worked. I simply added my own __init__.py, verified that the PYTHONPATH had all the paths with the correct casing (from another SO post) and done. geez, had i known it was so simple i would have done this earlier! Thanks!